# homebrew installation osx permission denied

Tags: macos, opencv

I'm following link to set up openCV on my mac

https://jjyap.wordpress.com/2014/05/24/installing-opencv-2-4-9-on-mac-osx-with-python-support/

and got following permission denied

I'm quite new to mac command line and openCV. So please do not skip some explanation

```
   yun-MacBook-Pro:~ sangwoneum$ cd /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
   yun-MacBook-Pro:site-packages sangwoneum$ 
   yun-MacBook-Pro:site-packages sangwoneum$ 
   yun-MacBook-Pro:site-packages sangwoneum$ ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv.py cv.py
   ln: cv.py: Permission denied
```

Comment: You shouldn't have write-permission in `/Library', so that explains the error.

Comment: If you're using Homebrew, there should be no need to put a link into `/Library/` or anywhere else to include a Python package. Just adjust your `PYTHONPATH.` Better yet: install Homebrew's Python, then use pip to install opencv for that Python and use that. Then you got an up-to-date Python as well, and you don't need to mess around with system files.

Comment: what is the pip install command line for opencv. ? I could not find it and that is why I looked up homebrew. pip install opencv  does not work

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't put a symbolic link into `/Library/`.

This is much better solved setting your `PYTHONPATH`:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

This will work only in your current session though, so let's make that setting permanent:

Open up your `.bashrc` in your home directory with your favourite text editor (`TextEdit` can work, but *be sure to use plain text (cmd-shift-T)*.

At the end of the file:

```
export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

(it's a bit different than above, in case there is already a PYTHONPATH defined).

Save, exit and source the file:

```
source $HOME/.bashrc
```

If you open up a new Terminal session/window/tab, this sourcing will happen automatically, and your path is correct.

---

Note that this solution only works if you're running Python from the command line. If you run it in another way, it may or may not work, and you might have to find another way to set your `PYTHONPATH`.